# MATLAB cell array of structs very slow compared to individual cell arrays for each field

Tags: matlab, struct, cell-array

I have some code where I have a certain class of objects, each of which has a number of fields. From an object oriented perspective, it's about as classic as you can get.

I initialized the code as:

```
object = cell(N, 1);
% Each field may contain matrices of different dimensions at each iteration
for i = 1 : N
    object{i}.field1 = ones(1000, 3);
    object{i}.field2 = imread('some_image.png');
    object{i}.field3 = (1:.002: 4);
    object{i}.field4 = im > 0;
    ...
    % And so on for more large matrices and such
end
```

I had previous coded this as:

```
field1 = cell(N, 1);
field2 = cell(N, 1);
field3 = cell(N, 1);
field4 = cell(N, 1);
....
for i = 1 : N
    field1{i} = ones(1000, 3);
    field2{i} = imread('some_image.png');
    field3{i} = (1:.002: 4);
    field4{i} = im > 0;
    ...
    % And so on for more large matrices and such
end
```

I then proceed to manipulate the values associated with each of the fields in each object in various ways. The second approach ran about 4 times faster than the first. The inefficiency is definitely due to this duality. The only code I changed was switching from multiple cell arrays to cell a array of structs.
I know arrays of structs have a reputation for being slower, but I also see structs recommended for passing into functions. What am I missing here?

I really like the coding neatness of the cell array of structures (particularly when you want to take a subset like `subset = object(1:4)`), but I obviously don't want to take the computational hit. What's the right choice here?

Better yet, is there a hidden, better third option?

Comment: In the first example, you don't even need to use cells. You are  dynamically updating the fields *and* size of the `object` cell array. Try initializing `object` like so: `object = struct('field1', cell(N,1), 'field2', cell(N,1), 'field3', cell(N,1), 'field4', cell(N,1))` and then filling in the values. Beyond that, you'd probably need to include more code/info in order to deduce whats causing the slow down.

Comment: @jucestain: I do need cells. I guess I missed that when generalizing my code, but I edited it in now. Each object contains different sized images and such. So while this one may have a 1100x1200 matrix, the next may have 980x740, and so on. Also, I have preallocated the object array, but you're right--the fields are not preallocated. I thought that after the first iteration, the fields would be all allocated though.

Comment: You don't need cells in the first example. Using what I suggested, you could do `object(1).field1 = ones(10,1)` and `object(2).field1 = ones(10,10)` which is fine. You only need cells in your second example.

Comment: @jucestain: Ahh you're saying just a standard array of structs... gotcha

Comment: The way you have the second part written, you are dynamically expanding the `object` cell array, and creating a new structure dynamically each iteration. You would only need to do this if you were housing different structs in each index of `object`. The way you have it coded, each index in `object` should have the same structure (with the same fields), so you can preallocate it and use it as an array of structs as you suggested, instead of a cell array.

Comment: @jucestain you are right. That just sped up my code four-fold. Thanks!

Comment: Went ahead and posted my comments as an answer to reap some sweet, sweet SO points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were led astray because in your initial approach, you *needed* cell arrays in order to house different sized arrays in each `field*` index.

However, when you decided to use structures in your second approach (the better approach), you didn't actually *need* to use cell arrays. So, if you examine this code segment:

```
for i = 1 : N
    object{i}.field1 = ones(1000, 3);
    object{i}.field2 = imread('some_image.png');
    object{i}.field3 = (1:.002: 4);
    object{i}.field4 = im > 0;
    ...
    % And so on for more large matrices and such
end
```

What's actually happening here is in each iteration, it is dynamically forming a structure on each iteration. Not only that, but every time you add a new field it is also dynamically adding a new field to that structure. This is only necessary if you are housing *different* structures in each index of the cell array.

However, since you are using the same structure in each index, you can simply use an array of structures. You can preallocate the entire thing by using:

```
object = struct('field1', cell(N,1), 'field2', cell(N,1), ...);
```

and then iterate over `object` and fill out each field as needed.